# Fillo to get record count in Groovy failed

Tags: groovy, jmeter, jsr223

I use `Fillo` to get values from an `xls`. I need to get record count,

I tried to use following code:

```
Recordset recordset=connection.executeQuery(strQuery);
int rcount = recordset.getCount().toInteger();
vars.put(rcount, rcount);
```

But I'm getting error message when execute it in a `JSR223 Sampler` in `JMeter`. 12 is the correct amount of records.

> javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No
>   signature of method: org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterVariables.put()
>   is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Integer,
>   java.lang.Integer) values: [12, 12] Possible solutions:
>   put(java.lang.String, java.lang.String), wait(), dump(), any(),
>   wait(long, int), get(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key/value for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html)'s put method are `String` type, so change type:

```
Recordset recordset=connection.executeQuery(strQuery);
String rcount = String.valueOf(recordset.getCount().toInteger());
vars.put(rcount, rcount);
```

if `recordset.getCount()` return `String` you can just assign it to `rcount`

Answer (score 1):

1. There is no need to convert the output of the `Recordset.getCount()` function to an [Integer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) as it is **already** the integer.
2. [`vars.put()` function](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html#put-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) accepts a [String](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) as the argument so if you want to proceed with this approach - you should convert the number of records into a String like:

   ```
   vars.put("rcount", rcount as String);
   ```
3. There is [`vars.putObject()` function](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html#putAll-org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterVariables-) which can store an arbitrary [Java Object](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) (or derivatives) into JMeter Variables so if later on you will be casting your `rcount` variable back to the integer - it makes sense to go for this function instead of doing 2 casts:

   ```
    vars.putObject("rcount", rcount);
   ```

More information: [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy)